# Aurelia ValidationRules.ensure using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I had an Aurelia project that was created with ES6 and Babel and I'm trying to convert it over to TypeScript.

In one area of code, I had something like this:

**tenant.js**

```
import {ValidationRules} from 'aurelia-validation'
export class Tenant{
    constructor(tenantObject){
        Object.assign(this, tenantObject);
    }
} 

ValidationRules
  .ensure(o => o.name).displayName("Tenant Name").required()
  ...
  .on(Tenant);
```

**system.js (VM)**

```
import {ValidationController} from 'aurelia-validation'
import {NewInstance} from 'aurelia-framework'
import {Tenant} from '../models/tenant'
import {BootstrapValidationRenderer} from 'elements/bootstrap-validation-renderer'

export class System{
    static inject = [DataService, NewInstance.of(ValidationController)]
    constructor(dataService, validationController){
       this.dataService = dataService
       this.validationController = validationController

       this.validationController.addRenderer(new BootstrapValidationRenderer())
    }

    async activate() {
       let data = await this.dataService.getTenant(1);
       this.tenant = new Tenant(data);
    }

    ...
}
```

**system.html**

```
...
<div class="form-group name" >
   <label for="pName" class="form-control-sm">Tenant Name</label>
   <input id="pName" type="text" autofocus class="form-control form-control-sm" value.bind="tenant.name & validate" />
</div>
```

However, I now get an error in `tenant.ts` stating that `property 'name' does not exist on type {}`.

I tried adding a `name` property to `Tenant` but that did not seem to help.

Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `aurelia-validation` [does not](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/) have typings. Hence you have to assert types like:

```
ValidationRules
  .ensure((o: Tenant) => o.name).displayName("Tenant Name").required()
  ...
  .on(Tenant);
```

But before that you should add `name` property to `Tenant` class:

```
export class Tenant{
    public name: string = ''

    constructor(tenantObject){
        Object.assign(this, tenantObject);
    }
}
```

P.S. fwiw even if `aurelia-validation` had typings, you would still have to assert type because it accepts class name in the very end of the methods chain.

Comment: Is there a way to get around having to add all the properties to the Tenant class?  In my case, the backend API already has a class definition for Tenant with all of its properties and the call to the DataService returns a JSON representation of that class.  I was hoping to NOT have to redefine that class on the front-end as well.  Is that possible?

Comment: Well you then will lose the benefit of using TS. But yes just add to the class `Tenant` this index signature: `[key: string]: any`

Comment: And if your backend has the definition, use NSwag or your client environment utilities to generate the DTOs for the client as Typescript classes or Typescript definitions.
For example, if you have Swagger on the host you can use something like NSwagStudio to generate Aurelia Typescript APIs directly.
If you're using ServiceStack you can install the `@servicestack/cli` library and use `typescript-ref` to auto-generate a `dto.ts` file with all of the DTO objects.

Try to find a way to auto-generate this sort of thing, otherwise you can never be sure that your client/server defs are in sync

Comment: Aurelia validation **does have typings**.  
See the [bundled aurelia-validation.d.ts](https://github.com/aurelia/validation/tree/master/dist) file in the plugin.

Comment: @Juliën Well, ok. But if I am correct, then this fact doesn't help in this case anyway? "because it accepts class name in the very end of the methods chain"?